# Trying to get a value from a website, but it gives 0.00 instead of the actual value which is not zero

Tags: python, selenium, browser, atom-editor

here is the value i try to grab with python selenium:

```
<div class="price">$<div style="display: inline-block;">24.42</div></div>
```

Here is my code:

```
Value = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, ('price'))
print(Value[1].text)
```

Here is my output in Atom console:

```
$
0.00
```

Important to know: That number i try to get changes every minute or so.
The class "price" shows two times on the website, thats why I choose the second element aka [1].

My question:
How to code this correctly, to get the value of 24.42? (The type of "Value" is div.)
If I get the value, I can use the same code to get another vaule to compare them.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Do you have multiple divs with the class name "price" ? if not then you should be accessing Value[0] not Value[1]

Comment: Yes, there are two values. Value[0] has a different value than Value[1]. But Value[0] also gives $ 0.00 back, even though it should be different.

Comment: Try adding a delay before `Value = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, ('price'))` and let me know if that helped